# How to find substring in string pointer

Tags: string, pointers, go

This simple question confused me.

Some function from external package returns `*string`

How can I find substring in returned `*string`?

Known Go functions as `strings.Index` and `Contains` requires `string` type and not pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dereference the pointer, so you get a `string` value. Then you may proceed as if it would not be a pointer.

[Spec: Address operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)

> For an operand `x` of pointer type `*T`, the pointer indirection `*x` denotes the [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` pointed to by `x`.

For example:

```
func main() {
    p := getPtr()
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains(*p, "go"))
    fmt.Println(strings.Contains(*p, "yo"))
}

func getPtr() *string {
    s := "gopher"
    return &s
}
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T1nvvYWn_FF)):

```
true
false
```